# Ember How is action triggered without specifying action in the hbs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app component my-component.hbs, I have

```
{{#my-grid gridInitialized="gridInstantiated" }}
```

Now in my-component.js, I have it defined as action below;

```
actions: {
    gridInstantiated: function (myGrid) {       
    }
}
```

How/Why does the above syntax for action work ?
Specifically

> 1. "gridInstantiated" is not defined as normal property in my-component.js
> 2. In the hbs, it is defined without the "action" keyword

Just wanted to know how it works given the above 2 points ?

*********EDITS************

Just to add, I have the below code on my-grid component init call;

```
this.sendAction('gridInitialized', Ember.$.proxy(this, function () {
    this.fetchData();
}));
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I get your question. `my-component.js` has no property `gridInstantiated` unless it's part of the class definition or passed from outter context. Say you would pass a value to the component from outside like `{{my-component gridInstantiated=something}}`. However, it has an action called `gridInstantiated` because it's defined in the `action` hash, just as you described above. The `my-grid` component has a property `gridInitialized` whose value is a plain string `"gridInstantiated"` because you pass it directly to the component. it's a plain string, nor function nor action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic action, for triggering the action they will use `this.sendAction("actionName")` this will look for the `actionName` function in action hash call that function with corresponding context.

Its very well explained in https://embermap.com/notes/26-a-note-on-actions

Comment: Thanks for that wonderful link...But still trying to connect my original question..I have updated the question with what I have in the component init...Wondering if that is what is doing the trick

Comment: yes. `sendAction` will accept string and call functions available in actions hash for component. and for controller/route we will use `send`

Comment: Just another question on "Example 2" example /Twiddle link on the page for loosing context

It says "this" would be undefined. But if I add an alert inside incrementCounter() [in example-2/controller.js], this actually alerts [object HTMLButtonElement]

Seems something wrong there ?

Comment: `this` is undefined that means it's not that controller context, its just like any other event listener. thats how addEventListener will work. `this` will refer DOM Element

Comment: So the article means that "this" is not literally undefined...Just that it will not refer to controller context